# What is the best way to learn about the Hadoop ecosystem

Tags: hadoop, data-science

I'm a Data Scientist with a background in pure mathematics, so i have a bit of a learning curve in terms of tools. By working in the industry for about a year, i understand that a Data Scientist should also know some Data Engineering. Can anyone point me to some resources? My current tech stack includes mostly of Python, (Pyspark) etc.

Comment: You don't really need to know Hadoop to learn more about Spark. For example, Databricks has plenty of resources for using spark, and has no Hadoop offering. What specifically from the ecosystem are you curious about? Storage? Scheduling? DataViz? Security? ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what exactly do you want to learn about Hadoop Ecosystem.

I would recommend you to start from this book:

- [Hadoop: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491901632) it can help you to understand how it works under the hood and get some understanding what Hadoop ecosystem consists of. You don't need all chapters of this book, but many of them may be really useful.

Also you should probably check this book

- [Spark - The Definitive Guide](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Spark-Definitive-Guide-Bill-Chambers/dp/1491912219) due to spark is commonly used in Data Science area. But it's more practical book than the previous one.